# Ruby regular expression to extract number

Tags: ruby, regex

I want to extract the begin number and the end number of some string.

Here is the test case.

```
 10000 => 1-0
100000 => 10-0
310000 => 31-0
310001 => 31-1
1200000 => 120-0
1200009 => 120-9
12000011 => 120-11
```

As you can see, there are always three zero just before the final number.
But I don't know how to extract the two number.

I've tried the following.

```
re = /[\d]+[0]{3}[\d]+/
str = '10000'

# Print the match result
str.scan(re) do |match|
    puts match.to_s
end
```

But the above code can only print the match string.

Comment: _extracting_ I suspect. OP?

Comment: You almost got it correct, try `/(\d+)0{3}(\d+)/`, and change `do |match|` to `do |begin_number, end_number|`. The matches are already a string when using *#scan*, so you can leave out the *#to_s* call.

Comment: Thanks, I edited  my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow the below code. Hope this helps.

```
regex_pattern = /(\d+)(0{3})(\d+)/

# For all numbers
numbers = ['10000', '100000', '310000', '310001', '1200000', '1200009', '12000011']
result = numbers.map do |number|
  #Every group captured can be use here with $number like for group 1 use $1. For group 2 use $2.
  number.gsub(regex_pattern) { |match_object| "#{$1}-#{$3}" }
end
p result

#For individual number
number = '10000'
p number.gsub(regex_pattern) { |match_object| "#{$1}-#{$3}" }
```

Let me know if this helps you or if you have any other doubts.

Comment: You can write `gsub(regex, '\1-\2')` instead.

Comment: That will be `1-000 `, `'\1-\3'` is the correct parameter.

Comment: @CodaChang - Glad to help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
test =<<_
10000
100000
310000
310001
1200000
1200009
12000011
_

r = /000(?=[1-9]|0\z)/

test.lines.each { |s| puts s.chomp.gsub(r,'-') }  
1-0
10-0
31-0
31-1
120-0
120-9
120-11
```

`(?=[1-9]|0\z)` is a *postive lookahead* that requires three zeros to be followed by a digit `1` to `9` or by `0` at the end of the string.